# emailable report not showing background-color in gmail

Tags: jenkins, outlook, gmail, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have created sending email after each build in Jenkins using editable email notification plugin. In body of mail I have added emailable-report.html generated by maven surefire report. I have discovered problem with appearance of this report in gmail - it not showing background-color at all in spite of outlook.

Appearance report in **outlook**:
[image: report in outlook]

Appearance report in **gmail**:
[image: report in gmail]

So the question is how can I modify CSS styles in emailable-report.html for correct view? Should I customize my report using TestNG Listener and IReporter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think someone would be interested in that.
Gmail client does not accept embedded styles. I have found decision move forward with generation html report in real time with IReporter and ItestNGListener. Here is nice work example https://github.com/djangofan/testng-custom-report-example thanks to djangofun